# findOne(id) Spring Repository returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the id passed as parameter from the URL in my controller and then I want to be able to get the name of the user with that id.
I have a `UserService` that has this function :

```
public User getUserById(long id);
```

The implementation of this function is :

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Override
public User getUserById(long id) {
    return userRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

And this is the controller where I want to access it :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"getId"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getClientStat(@RequestParam(value="getId", required = true) String getId) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    long userId=0;
    userId=Long.parseLong(getId);
    User u=userService.getUserById(userId);
    modelAndView.addObject("id", u.getName());
    modelAndView.setViewName("user");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And I have an entity `User` with `Long` `id`, `String` `name`, `String` `lastName` and getters and setters for each. 
But when running this code it returns null pointer exception, which comes from the part where I call `getUserId(userId)`.
This is my user entity:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;    

    ... 
}
```

And User Repository :

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Service interface:

```
public interface UserService{
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
    public User getUserById(long id);
}
```

In my controller I have :

```
@Autowired
private AdminService adminService;

private UserService userService;
```

Could it be possibly a mistake in the annotations used ? Should I use an annotation in the UserService class ? The `@Service` annotation is used in the `UserServiceImpl` class.

Comment: Please post your code for `User` and `UserRepository`.

Comment: Done, and thank you

Comment: Post your exception stack trace. What *exactly* throws the NPE? It seems `userService` may be `null`, how is `userService` injected in controller? Relevant code is missing.

Comment: @JenX I didn't notice anything wrong with your repo and entity. Please post the service class and exception stack.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much ! I fixed it. I actually hadn't put appropriate annotations. Hadn't put Autowired when calling the service in the controller and Service in the service.
I'm so sorry I may have wasted your time , and thank you for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually hadn't put appropriate annotations. Hadn't put `@Autowired` on `UserService` when calling the service in the controller. Using the annotation my problem is gone.